# Union over disjoint union

Tags: general-topology

How does the normal union behave over the disjoint union?  For instance, if i have some indexed collection of disjoint unions between two sets, what is the union over the whole collection?

Comment: How do you define union of topological spaces? I also assume that by disjoint union of topological spaces you mean the topological sum.

Comment: I'm really confused by what you mean by "union over the whole collection".  I think you need to define the objects you're working with a bit more explicitly before we can understand your question clearly enough to provide an answer.